# Empty field message is showing for a few seconds

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I'm trying to understand it using a tutorial. I started with registration form validation. I made a script and it's working fine, but message shows for a few seconds. I want message to show until user fills the field again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <style>
  p { color:red; margin:4px; }
  b { color:blue; }
  </style>
  <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p></p>

 <form id="form1"> 
  Name<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
    <script>   
            $(document).ready(function(){
        //var msg=$("p").text("Are you sure?");
        $("#form1").click(function(){
            if ($('#fname').val()=="") {
            //$("#ms").show("slow");
            $("p").html("Are you sure?");
            //$(this).show("Are you sure?");

            }
        });
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should to use `$('#form1').submit(function() {});` instead of `$("#submit").click(function(){});`

Comment: if tutorial use `click` event, search for other one, this will teach you bad practice.

Comment: Why not use window.confirm popup box rather than changing a p element?  That way you don't have to add extra buttons and can easily add functionality for the yes no

Comment: @ eicto :-you are right i made certain change and i paste it change code now it is fine.please solve the issue....

Comment: @user1817669 now can you please tell me whats your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hi do one thing replace below code with your  code

```
  <script>   


     $(document).ready(function(){
        //var msg=$("p").text("Are you sure?");
           $("#submit").click(function(){
           if ($('#fname').val()=="")
           {
             //$("#ms").show("slow");
              $("p").html("Are you sure?");
             return false;
            //$(this).show("Are you sure?");
           }
        });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: both are right but what the concept behind that.i want to know

Comment: Hi if you use return true it will submit your form weather you leave the field blank but if you have checked the validation and its true mean you left the field blank in such case you use return false it wont submit your form till you fill up all the field and submit again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Better to use `<form>`'s event, rather than `onclick` for `submit`.

Change your `script` to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //var msg=$("p").text("Are you sure?");
        $("#form1").submit(function(){
            if ($('#fname').val()=="") {
                //$("#ms").show("slow");
                $("p").html("Are you sure?");
                //$(this).show("Are you sure?");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The reason is, you should not submit the form in the HTML Way. You need to submit using JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `return false` at the end of your function

```
$("#form1").submit(function(){
    if ($('#fname').val()=="") {
        //$("#ms").show("slow");
        $("p").html("Are you sure?");
        //$(this).show("Are you sure?");
    }
    return false;
});
```

and for  your second question use `keyup`

```
$('#fname').keyup(function(){
  if(empty($(this).val()))
      $("p").show();
  else
     $("p").hide();
});
```

however.. i recommend you to use some jquery [validation plugins](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) rather than writing your own...